# How many strings are produced in a .toString.split(","); call?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Suppose I have the following code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("521,214");
String[] result = sb.toString().split(",");
```

My question is: does `toString().split(",")` generate 2 strings or 3 strings? 
I know that the result String array will have 2 strings - but the `toString()` call will also generate a string as well - that isn't returned?

Basically, I'm trying to limit the number of strings created for performance purposes and want to know if the `toString()` call brings the total number of strings created to 3?

Comment: You could run the code and see it for yourself...

Comment: This will not compile first

Comment: Looking to optimise for one String is not worth the effort for the minuscule amount of potential gain.

Comment: 1. Why not just use `"521,214".split(",");`? and 2. I honestly doubt that this "performance issue" is something you need to worry about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be five `String` object created in total by these two lines:

- `"521,214"` object passed to `StringBuilder`'s constructor. This object is in the interned pool of strings,
- `","` String object passed to `split`. This object is also in the interned pool of strings,
- An equivalent `"521,214"` object produced by `toString`. Each call of `toString` produces a new `String` object. There is no optimization to see if in identical string object has been requested before.
- Two `String` objects for `"521"` and `"214"` produced by the `split` method

It goes without saying that a `String[]` array object will be created to hold `"521"` and `"214"` objects returned from the `split` method.

Comment: This question is kind of vague for me. The OP says *how many Strings are formed internally*. That number will surely be greater than 5, as the split method uses an `ArrayList` of `String` internally. The source code is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> *does toString().split(",") generate 2 strings or 3 strings*

neither 2 nor 3, split returns an array object, that the array has been made of strings is another story...

if your question is how many strings are in that array then the answer is: it depends of how many tockens (",") are found in the original string that you are splitting...

Answer (score 1):

It will create a String array with 2 strings in it.

You can test this anytime by printing out the array:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("521,214");
String[] result = sb.toString().split(",");
for(String s : result)
    System.out.println(s);
```

The method `.split()` will **remove** the string that you are splitting by.

Comment: But internally, the total number of strings created are 3 correct? sb.toString() creates a string, then split returns an array of 2 strings?

Comment: Yes but that is a minor "performance issue". Surely it is not the cause of a bottleneck. Also, that is the least number of strings i believe you can have when splitting into 2.